# What should be my class structure to parse JSON in GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "response": {},
    "errorMessage": {
        "error": [
            {
                "errorId": 260003,
                "domain": "ads",
                "subdomain": "asd",
                "severity": "asd",
                "category": "asd",
                "message": "asdsa  asd ad",
                "errorName": "UnAuthorized"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Currently I have the following class structure:

```
public class JSONCollection
    private Response response;
    private ErrorMessage error;

public class Response 
    private String collectionId;
    private String url;

public class ErrorMessage 
    private List<ErrorValues> error;

public class ErrorValues 
    private String errorId;
    private String domain;
    private String subdomain;
    private String severity;
    private String category;
    private String message;
    private String errorName;
```

I have setters/get set for all private variables

But when I do a `JSONCollection cJson = gson.fromJson(JSONValue,JSONCollection.class);` I get cJson as a `null`.

How to get it right?

Comment: [Use this tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate schema for your JSON

Comment: @JigarJoshi When I press preview with my JSON nothing shows up

Comment: It does for me,paste your JSON in that field, select source type = JSON, Annotation style= None

Comment: JsonCollection's ErrorMessage should be named `errorMessage`, not `error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) shown by @JigarJoshi to generate my schema.

The only difference I found is I had to change the class name from `ErrorValues` to `Error`