# Can't read json file

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

Here's my method where im reading json file.

```
private void LoadTabaksFromJson() {

    InputStream raw = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tabaks);
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw));


    ListOfTabaks listOfTodos = new Gson().fromJson(reader, ListOfTabaks.class);
    List<Tabak> todoList = listOfTodos.getTodoArrayList();

    for (Tabak item: todoList){
        mDataBase.insert(TabakTable.NAME,null,getContentValues(item));
    }
}


public class ListOfTabaks {

    protected ArrayList<Tabak> tabakArrayList;

    public ArrayList<Tabak> getTodoArrayList(){
        return tabakArrayList;
    }
}
```

And Exeption

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface
>   method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.hookah.roma.hookahmix.TabakLab.LoadTabaksFromJson(TabakLab.java:61)
>                                                                                  at com.hookah.roma.hookahmix.TabakLab.(TabakLab.java:32)
>                                                                                  at com.hookah.roma.hookahmix.TabakLab.get(TabakLab.java:37)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.hookah.roma.hookahmix.TabakListFragment.updateUI(TabakListFragment.java:38)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.hookah.roma.hookahmix.TabakListFragment.onCreateView(TabakListFragment.java:32)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentsToInvisible(FragmentManager.java:2323)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2136)

And json file :

```
  {
  "tabaksArrayList":[
    {
      "name":"Абрикос",
      "description":"Со вкусом Абрикоса",
      "rating":"4.1",
      "favourite":"1",
      "family":"Al fakher"
    },
    {
      "name":"Ананас",
      "description":"Со вкусом Ананаса",
      "rating":"4.1",
      "favourite":"1",
      "family":"Al fakher"
    },
    {
      "name":"Апельсин",
      "description":"Со вкусом Апельсина",
      "rating":"4.1",
      "favourite":"1",
      "family":"Al fakher"
    },
    {
      "name":"Апельсин с мятой",
      "description":"Со вкусом Апельсина с мятой",
      "rating":"4.1",
      "favourite":"1",
      "family":"Al fakher"
    },
```

Comment: and which is the line no 61 ?

Comment: @Prashant probably the line with the enhanced for loop

Comment: 61 :  for (Tabak item: todoList){
 I understand that a exception because of the list is empty but WHYY ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your json schema issue, i'm guessing `listOfTodos` return null. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794916/what-should-be-my-class-structure-to-parse-json-in-gson) to generate your schema.

But sometimes that tools can make us confuse so i tried to create your schema manually like this:

TabakRoot.java

```
public class TabakRoot {

@SerializedName("tabaksArrayList")
private List<TabakItem> tabakItem = null;

public List<TabakItem> getTabakItem() {
    return tabakItem;
}}
```

TabakItem.java

```
public class TabakItem {

@SerializedName("family")
@Expose
private String tabakFamily;

public String getTabakFamily() {
    return tabakFamily;
}}
```

finally

```
TabakRoot listOfTodos = new Gson().fromJson(reader, TabakRoot.class);
List<TabakItem> todoList = listOfTodos.getTabakItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put your json file in assets folder

use AsyncTask to protect from ANR like situtation

```
onBackground(){
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream stream = activity.getAssets().open("ur_json_file_in_assets_folder.json");
        int size = stream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

then parse in

```
onPostExecute(String str){
JsonObject object = new JsonObject(str);
JsonArray arr = object.getJsonArray("tabaksArrayList");
...}
```

more details at  [ParseJsonFileAsync.java](https://gist.github.com/ashmeh6/fbff0aabfb16a407a497156b282783ea)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not initialising your ArrayList, try changing:

```
protected ArrayList<Tabak> tabakArrayList;
```

for:

```
protected ArrayList<Tabak> tabakArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialising `tabakArrayList`, add a constructor to your ListOfTabaks as following

```
public ListOfTabaks{
    tabakArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and you should be fine